# Converting PLC hexadecimal values to real world values(arithmetic types-int,float,bool,double etc) using a convert button in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

This is the form that has been created by me which displays all the data being fetched from plc into hexadecimal format which now I want to be converted into real world format using that convert button.

[image: Form]

The convert button does not convert the values and simply prints the same hexadecimal output. I have also mentioned the convert button code.

Readbtn click that reads the data from plc

```
private void ReadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GetSelectedDB();
}
```

GetSelectedDB method

```
void GetSelectedDB() {
    int Size = 65536; // 64 K (the maximum for a S7400)
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[Size];
    txtDBGet.Text = "";
    int Result = Client.DBGet(System.Convert.ToInt32(TxtDB.Text),Buffer, ref Size);
    ShowResult(Result);
    if (Result == 0) {
        HexDump(txtDBGet, Buffer, Size);
    }
}
```

Here is the Hexdump code that prints the output into a textbox

```
private void HexDump(TextBox DumpBox, byte[] bytes, int Size) {
    if (bytes == null)
        return;
    int bytesLength = Size;
    int bytesPerLine = 16;

    char[] HexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF".ToCharArray();

    int firstHexColumn =
        8                   // 8 characters for the address
        + 3;                  // 3 spaces

    int firstCharColumn = firstHexColumn
        + bytesPerLine * 3       // - 2 digit for the hexadecimal value and 1 space
        + (bytesPerLine - 1) / 8 // - 1 extra space every 8 characters from the 9th
        + 2;                  // 2 spaces 

    int lineLength = firstCharColumn
        + bytesPerLine           // - characters to show the ascii value
        + Environment.NewLine.Length; // Carriage return and line feed (should normally be 2)

    char[] line = (new String(' ', lineLength - 2) + Environment.NewLine).ToCharArray();
    int expectedLines = (bytesLength + bytesPerLine - 1) / bytesPerLine;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(expectedLines * lineLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesLength; i += bytesPerLine) {
        line[0] = HexChars[(i >> 28) & 0xF];
        line[1] = HexChars[(i >> 24) & 0xF];
        line[2] = HexChars[(i >> 20) & 0xF];
        line[3] = HexChars[(i >> 16) & 0xF];
        line[4] = HexChars[(i >> 12) & 0xF];
        line[5] = HexChars[(i >> 8) & 0xF];
        line[6] = HexChars[(i >> 4) & 0xF];
        line[7] = HexChars[(i >> 0) & 0xF];

        int hexColumn = firstHexColumn;
        int charColumn = firstCharColumn;

        for (int j = 0; j < bytesPerLine; j++) {
            if (j > 0 && (j & 7) == 0)
                hexColumn++;
            if (i + j >= bytesLength) {
                line[hexColumn] = ' ';
                line[hexColumn + 1] = ' ';
                line[charColumn] = ' ';
            } else {
                byte b = bytes[i + j];
                line[hexColumn] = HexChars[(b >> 4) & 0xF];
                line[hexColumn + 1] = HexChars[b & 0xF];
                line[charColumn] = (b < 32 ? '·' : (char)b);
            }
            hexColumn += 3;
            charColumn++;
        }
        result.Append(line);
    }
    DumpBox.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

This is the convert button that that I have used but isn't converting the data into desired format but just shows me the same data

```
private void Convert_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string hexValue = txtDBGet.Text.ToString();
    char[] myarr = hexValue.ToCharArray(); 
    string[] ids = textdbconv.Text.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < myarr.Length; i++) {
        textdbconv.AppendText(myarr[i].ToString() + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: And by *"real world format"* / *"desired format"* you mean something like ASCII / UTF?

Comment: areithmetic types (boolean,int,char,double,long,floating)@ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: Well, currently `Convert_btn_Click` splits a string into separate characters and puts them back together - not really surprising that it shows you *"the same data"*. Whatever logic you ought to use for this conversion is completely missing. To know what part of the data represents which datatype(s) you need look that up in your hardware's [development manual or protocol specification](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/24352751/which-types-of-connection-protocols-do-the-s7-300-400-cpus-and-the-cps-support-by-default-?dti=0&lc=en-WW).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer ohk sir.. :)